# Use XSLT and jQuery together

Tags: jquery, html, xml, xslt

I am using XSLT to transform xml file to html so it can be viewed in a browser.

My XSL file basically defines a number of tables (populated from my XML file).

My HTML file is like below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Title</title>   
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function applyXSLT()
    {       
             // do transfrom
             resultdiv.innerHTML = transformResults;
    }
//-->   

</script>
</head>
<body class="main" onLoad="applyXSLT()">
<div id="resultdiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything is working at this point. Now I want to use jQuery to help with sorting on the tables.

My question is how do I do that? Where do I put the jQuery stuff?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [RTFM](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) ? You are tagging XSLT, but your question only rely on JQuery subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach of sorting is using xslt template sort the xml data, this is how you can sort in xslt:

```
 <xsl:sort select="Name" order="ascending" data-type="text"/>
```

Then you need to dynamicly change the sorting field based on the column.

Other approaches would be using some plugins to sort on the UI,jquery datatable, tablesorter etc.

Comment: XSLT only allows one-way sorting, i.e ascending or descending. What I want to achieve is click on the table column header to sort two-way. I am considering using the jquery tablesorter here: [link](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). Any ideas how to use it with XSLT?

Comment: you can retrieve the xsl attribute like this,then adjust sort accordingly:
  var Sort = xslTemplate.selectSingleNode("//xsl:sort/@select");
  var Order = xslTemplate.selectSingleNode("//xsl:sort/@order");
  var DataType = xslTemplate.selectSingleNode("//xsl:sort/@data-type");